# Do not fire if element has class 'load' or child contains '.delete'

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>This should fire</li>
   <li>This should not fire, but does <div class="delete">Delete</div></li>
   <li class="load">This does not fire as expected</li> 
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:not(.load):not(:has(.delete))', function() {
    alert('fire');
});
```

Any idea how I can prevent the jQuery from firing when the li has a child element with class `.delete`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Comment: That works.  I copied and pasted it into jsFiddle and it worked with no changes.

Comment: It does work... I don't know why I was having issues earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/8ezUA/)). That said, you used another opening `li` tag instead of a closing tag... so, you're getting an unexpected list item.

```
<ul>
    <li>This should fire</li>
    <li>This should not fire, but does<div class="delete">Delete</div></li>
    <li class="load">This does not fire (as expected)</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You're right... it is working. I have no idea why I couldn't get it to work earlier. hm.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
   var currentLi = $(this);
   if(currentLi.find('.delete').length == 0 && !currentLi.hasClass('load')) {
       alert('fire');
       return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: edited just now. Try now.

Comment: yup. cached jquery objects

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$('li:not(.load):not(:has(.delete))').on('click', function() {    
   alert('fire');
});
```

Comment: Why are you voting down?
Thats exactly what he asked for.
`how I can prevent the jQuery from firing when the li has a child element with class .delete`

Comment: accepted. but voting down in this case is not fair.
His question(load part) was a clue between the html.
Asking the question right is important than the answer.